# What Security Policies are necessary to enable the Annotate function?

Tags: security, content-hub

I am unable to get the Annotate function working for a non-SuperUser.
[image: Annotation button for SuperUser]

My test user sees this (note missing Annotation option):
[image: No Annotation option]

And has a group with these policies:
[image: Security rights for test group]

Things I've tried:

- Enabling all rights on M.Asset.
- Enabling full CRUD on M.File and M.Annotation.
- Giving Read to all Annotate related portal pages.
- Adding ANY access for all the "builtin" groups.
- Cleared all caches.
- Restarted the sandbox.

Version 3.4.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the rule for both entity definitions M.Asset and M.File, and then you have to select ReadAnnotations and CreateAnnotations permissions.

[image]

Your portal pages rule is fine, but remove the rules you did for M.Annotations, M.File, M.Asset and use the the rule I detailed. That should give your user annotation read/write permission.

Comment: Confirmed! https://i.imgur.com/Cd9LvI4.jpg

Comment: Note that in addition to the rights in my screenshot, and the one's Eric shared, I also needed to  add M.Builtin.ContentAdministrator. When I've had a chance to pin down the minimal set of rights to get this to work, I'll post a second answer.